# How to embed dependencies using urequire

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I use grunt-urequire plugin to compile my project-1's modules into single file (let's call it `project-1.js`). Config looks like this:

```
urequire: {
  umd: {
    template: 'UMD',
    path: 'src',
    dstPath: 'dist/umd'
  },

  dev: {
    template: 'combined',
    path: 'src',
    main: 'Main',
    dstPath: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.js'
  },

  min: {
    derive: ['dev', '_defaults'],
    dstPath: 'dist/<%= pkg.name %>-<%= pkg.version %>.min.js',
    optimize: 'uglify2'
  },

  _defaults: {
    useStrict: true,
    noConflict: true,
    bundle: {
      dependencies: {
        exports: {
          root: {
            'Main': 'Project1'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Project-1 depends on project-2 which is also managed by grunt-urequire. In `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "project2": "^0.1",
    ...
}
```

Now I want to embed project-2 dependency into project-1 on build so that one could just do

```
<script src="project-1.js"></script>
```

in browser and don't include project-2 manually.

I know [browserify](http://browserify.org/) supports this, but can I do it using urequire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uRequire doesn't embed external dependencies (like `jquery`, `underscore` etc) into the `combined.js` file, unlike browserify which is the only option (as far as I know) and its also the default behavior of `r.js`.

This is partly intentional, cause **its better to load** (either using RequireJS or `<script/>`) these external libraries from a CDN: your user's browser might have already cached them last time it loaded your app (or someone else's app). And next time *your* `myApp.js` changes, **it will download only that** and not a monolithic bundle that contains all the same external libs all over again.

uRequire actually goes a long way to make sure these are loaded externally, whether on nodejs (using plain node's `require`) or the browser, using AMD or the exported global properties (like `window.$`, `window._` or whatever the external library is mapped to).

I would imagine you can easily override this behavior: just place `project-2.js` whenever you build it onto the source folder of *project-1*, and just use it in project-1 as a normal dependency.

Alternatively you can again build/convert all *project-2* files as AMD (not combined) into the source folder of project-1 and use them as being part of it.

Finally, you could just symlink the project-2 source into project-1, its supported on unix/linux for decades and also on Windows 7 onwards. Then uRequire will convert the sources from both projects only once and build as a single output.

Ideally I would like to have virtual sources (see https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire/issues/40) so you can leave both projects separate (i.e not build one into the other), but build both as one output.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately uRequire doesn't support this for the moment. Issue to track is https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire/issues/26

Answer (score 1):

If you want to version the 2 projects on the same git repository because they are updated together and have the same release lifecycle, you can have a build script in 2 parts:

- First part is to compile project2 (project2/src)
- Second part is to compile project1 (project1/src)

During the compilation of project2, you can copy the distributed JS of project2 into project1/src so that it is automatically.

---

If you have different release lifecycles, you can use some grunt tool to download the dependency from a CDN / NPM and put it into the project1/src folder before packaging project 1

This is somehow what is done by Browserify by using NPM, but it would probably be the same with Bower, components or custom JS code to download the dependencies. I would recommend using a tool like NPM however because it also download transitive dependencies (if one day project2 introduces a dependency, you won't have to touch project1 build...)

Finally, I don't know uRequire but maybe you could be inspired by [this project](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded), which embeds dependencies in the packaged version (eventie)